# List Oldest Registries and Get Status

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with a list of OfficeLicensePurchases.

In that list I need to count how many Offices were created in each year.

And I know that by the earliest license object.

Also, I need to count in each year, how many of that created Offices still have an active license(in the current year)

The Colection:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "514de62f-0a4c-46c8-ba66-5692935f0930",
    "OfficeId": "09ac58f0-8d2a-42ec-ba47-f518dd9d0904",
    "PlanName": "Plan 50",
    "PlanPrice": 777,
    "PaidValue": 330,
    "CreationDate": {
      "$date": "2017-03-08T03:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "Status": "Active"
  },
  {
    "_id": "e41a5923-3a69-43bb-87a4-f1169e172e2e",
    "OfficeId": "9679fdf7-02a1-4a1f-b0f0-17d3505e86e3",
    "PlanName": "Plan 50",
    "PlanPrice": 777,
    "PaidValue": 330,
    "CreationDate": {
      "$date": "2019-03-08T03:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "Status": "Inactive"
  },
  {
    "_id": "d314a8bf-0147-4aee-8357-f36db686c85a",
    "OfficeId": "eab54926-0c11-4c9f-aee2-7fbeabad4135",
    "PlanName": "Plan 50",
    "PlanPrice": 777,
    "PaidValue": 330,
    "CreationDate": {
      "$date": "2021-03-08T03:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "Status": "Active"
  },
  {
    "_id": "d314a8bf-0147-4aee-8357-f36db686c85b",
    "OfficeId": "eab54926-0c11-4c9f-aee2-7fbeabad4135",
    "PlanName": "Plan 100",
    "PlanPrice": 7776,
    "PaidValue": 3308,
    "CreationDate": {
      "$date": "2021-03-08T03:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "Status": "Active"
  },
  {
    "_id": "d314a8bf-0147-4aee-8357-f36db686c856",
    "OfficeId": "eab54926-0c11-4c9f-aee2-7fbeabad4139",
    "PlanName": "Plan 100",
    "PlanPrice": 7776,
    "PaidValue": 3308,
    "CreationDate": {
      "$date": "2021-03-08T09:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "Status": "Active"
  },
  {
    "_id": "d314a8bf-0147-4aee-8357-f36db686c855",
    "OfficeId": "eab54926-0c11-4c9f-aee2-7fbeabad4135",
    "PlanName": "Plan 100",
    "PlanPrice": 7776,
    "PaidValue": 3308,
    "CreationDate": {
      "$date": "2023-03-08T09:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "Status": "Active"
  },
  {
    "_id": "d314a8bf-0147-4aee-8357-f36db686c859",
    "OfficeId": "eab54926-0c11-4c9f-aee2-7fbeabad4135",
    "PlanName": "Plan 100",
    "PlanPrice": 7776,
    "PaidValue": 3308,
    "CreationDate": {
      "$date": "2023-03-08T09:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "Status": "Active"
  }
]
```

Expected result:

```
[
 {CreationYear: 2017, NewOffices: 1, Active: 1},
 {CreationYear: 2019, NewOffices: 1, Active: 1},
 {CreationYear: 2021, NewOffices: 2, Active: 1}
]
```

**So I need:**

**1. Count of the **Oldest License** for each Office, so I can have how many Offices were created in each year.**

**2. How many of those Offices have an Active License in the CurrentYear. So I can know how many are still Active in the System.**

Please, how do I manage that?

Comment: how did 2018 come. anyway something like https://mongoplayground.net/p/YFOd459KHr5 ?